# Calculate consecutive items in a list

Tags: python, list, foreach

I am newbie,

I have lists like this:

`List1= ['I', 'P', 'P', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'P', 'I', 'I', 'I']`

`List2= ['P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'P', 'I', 'I', 'P']`

`List3= ['P', 'P', 'P', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'P', 'P', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'P', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I']`

I want to calculate the consecutive 'I' only if the last item of the list is an 'I'

`In our list1 it's 1-5-3, 3 is not greater then 5, so it's not true`

`In our list2 it will ignore it because the last index is a 'P'`

`In our list3 it's 4-3-6, 6 is greater then 3 and then 4 so it's True`

For `all lists` if the last consecutive group is greater then all precedent groups it gives `True`

I tried this but gives nothing:

```
n=0
For items in lists1:
 if list1 [-1] == "P":
else:
List1 [n]
n+=1
...
```

But can't progress

Help is appreciated
Thanks to all of you

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I tried something yes, now i edit my post but i can't progress, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna use itertools groupby here -

```
from itertools import groupby

def check_list(l):
    if l[-1] == 'I':
        result = [len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(l) if k=='I']
        if max(result) == result[-1]:
            return True
    return False

check_list(List1) # False
check_list(List2) # False
check_list(List3) # True
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def f(l):
    if l[-1] != 'I':
        return False
    else:
        c = 0; out = []
        for index, item in enumerate(l):
            if item == 'I':
                c+= 1
                if index == len(l)-1 and c != 0:
                    out.append(c)
            else:
                if c != 0:
                    out.append(c)
                    c=0                             
        return out[-1] == max(out)
print(f(List1))
print(f(List2))
print(f(List3))
```

Output:

```
False
False
True
```

Let me explain:

1. First it checks if the last item is `'I'`, if it is then it returns false.
2. If not, then it loops through the list, and each time it encounters consecutive 'I's then the counter is added. If the item is *not* `'I'` then the counter is added to the list and reset to zero. This way we get a list of no. of consecutive `'I'`s.
3. Then it checks if the list's last item(`out[-1]`) is the `max` value of the list. If so, it returns `True`, if not, then `False`.